# Python ftplib.error_perm: 530 Login authentication failed

Tags: python, ftp-server

I want to write a script to connect my FTP server , but it can not work for me.

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp=FTP()
ftp.set_debuglevel(2)
ftp.connect('192.169.137.100')
ftp.login('test','test')
ftp.dir()
ftp.close()
```

and when build this script, I got these information

```
*get* '220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------\r\n'
*get* '220-You are user number 1 of 50 allowed.\r\n'
*get* '220-Local time is now 23:46. Server port: 21.\r\n'
*get* '220-This is a private system - No anonymous login\r\n'
*get* '220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.\r\n'
*resp* '220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------\n220-You are user number 1 of 50 allowed.\n220-Local time is now 23:46. Server port:  21.\n220-This is a private system - No anonymous login\n220 You will be   disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.'
*cmd* 'USER test'
*put* 'USER test\r\n'
*get* '331 User test OK. Password required\r\n'
*resp* '331 User test OK. Password required'
*cmd* 'PASS ****'
*put* 'PASS ****\r\n'
*getTraceback (most recent call last):
 File "D:\photoWebSite\py_test.py", line 9, in <module>
* '530 Login authentication failed\r\n'
*resp* '530 Login authentication failed'
    ftp.login('test','test')
    File "D:\LinuxSL\python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 393, in login
    if resp[0] == '3': resp = self.sendcmd('PASS ' + passwd)
File "D:\LinuxSL\python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 249, in sendcmd
    return self.getresp()
File "D:\LinuxSL\python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 224, in getresp
    raise error_perm, resp
ftplib.error_perm: 530 Login authentication failed
```

I hope some help please .

Comment: I can connect to my ftp server when I use command line .

Answer (score 13):

You may try to use `FTP_TLS` as following:

```
from ftplib import FTP_TLS
ftp=FTP_TLS()
ftp.set_debuglevel(2)
ftp.connect('192.169.137.100', 22)
ftp.sendcmd('USER test')
ftp.sendcmd('PASS test')
ftp.dir()
ftp.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

I used `ftplib` and was unable to connect becuase of `error_perm`, used `pysftp` and it worked for me.

```
import pysftp
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None   
myHostname = "abc.org"
myUsername = "username"
myPassword = "password"

with pysftp.Connection(host=myHostname, username=myUsername, password=myPassword, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
    print ("Connection succesfully stablished ... ")
    directory_structure = sftp.listdir_attr()
    for attr in directory_structure:
        print (attr.filename, attr)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Ensure the server supports credential login!**

**There is a chance it only supports annonymous login**

Use:

```py
def connect(host, username, passwd, port):
    from ftplib import FTP
    print(f'host:{host}, username:{username} passwd:{passwd}, port: {port}')
    #instance of ftp
    ftp = FTP()
    #set the debig level
    ftp.set_debuglevel(2)
    #connect to ftp
    ftp.connect(host=str(host), port=int(port))
    print('connected')
    #login
    print('login in.....')
    if username:
        if passwd:
            ftp.login(user=username, passwd=passwd)
        else:
            print('Password required')
            exit(0)
    else:
        #login without username and password
        ftp.login()
    #return the dirs list and ftp object
    dirs = list()
    ftp.retrlines("LIST", dirs.append())
    return ftp, dirs
```

The code above validates whether th user passed a username and password.If so, logs in with credentials.IF not logs in annonymously.But I suggest you first find out and enable credential login for the server.Try the python ftp server at:https://github.com/malgulam/100ProjectsOfCode/blob/main/ftpclient/ftpclient_simple/ftp_server.py and https://github.com/keepitsimple/pyFTPclient and fire up your client and use the connect function above.

Answer (score 0):

just try to disable passive mode, it should work:

```
ftp.set_pasv(0)
```